# How to rectify the page not found error in WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

[image]

Once downloaded and installed the WordPress theme it does not load in our localhost server. Could you please clarify this error?

Comment: what does your URL look like?

Comment: Try re-saving your permalinks – go to Settings > Permalinks and click Save Changes.

Comment: Second what @kisabelle mentioned. If it was working before but no longer works, try going to Settings > Permalinks and clicking the save button again.

Comment: My URL looks like " http://localhost/mysite/ " @BretWeinraub

Comment: I tried your idea but my problem was not solved @kisabelle

Comment: My guess would be your .htaccess file is wrong [if you use apache, of course].   You might want to walk through the steps here and make sure you are doing it all correctly.   https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-in-a-subdirectory-step-by-step/